# jquery.tipTip displays tooltip text randomly

Tags: jquery

```js
       
    scheduler.config.details_on_create = true;
    scheduler.config.details_on_dblclick = true;
    scheduler.config.drag_move = false;    
    scheduler.config.xml_date = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i';      
    scheduler.config.full_day = true;   
    scheduler.config.drag_resize = false; 
    scheduler.config.drag_create = false;  
    scheduler.keys.edit_save = -1;  
    scheduler.xy.bar_height = 21; 
                 
    scheduler.createTimelineView({
     name: 'AssessorsScheduler',
     x_unit: 'day',
     x_date: '%D %M %d',
     x_step: 1,
     x_size: 14,  
     y_unit: scheduler.serverList('MyList', AssessorsArray),
     y_property: 'UserID',
     event_dy: 'full',
     render: 'bar',
     dx: 160
    }); 
     
    scheduler.locale.labels.section_Assessor = 'Assessors Scheduler'; // This is a section  in a lightbox
      
    scheduler.form_blocks["my_editor"]={
     render:function(sns){
      return "<div id='AssessorLightboxDiv' class='dhx_cal_ltext' style='height:440px;'> <table width='630px' cellspacing='1'> <tbody> <tr> <td class='LightBoxHeadingCell'> Location : </td> <td class='LightBoxNormalCell'> <select name='AssessorsLocationDropDown' id='AssessorsLocationDropDown' onchange='AssessorsLocationDropDownOnChange();'> <option selected = '' value='Evaluators Office'>Evaluators Office</option> <option value='Clinic'>Clinic</option> <option value='N/A'>N/A</option> </select> </td> <td class='LightBoxHeadingCell' id='ClinicAssociationTD' style='display:none;'> <span title='Required' class='Required'>* </span>Association : </td> <td class='LightBoxNormalCell' id='ClinicAssociationListTD' style='display:none;'> <select name='ClinicAssociationDropDown' id='ClinicAssociationDropDown'> <option selected = '' value=''></option> </select> </td> </tr> <tr id='ReasonRow' style='display:none;'> <td class='LightBoxHeadingCell'> <span title='Required' class='Required'>* </span>Reason : </td> <td class='LightBoxNormalCell'> <select name='ReasonDropDown' id='ReasonDropDown'> <option selected = '' value=''></option> <option value='Personal Leave'>Personal Leave</option> <option value='Sick'>Sick</option> <option value='Stat Holiday'>Stat Holiday</option> <option value='Training'>Training</option> <option value='Vacation'>Vacation</option> </select> </td> <td class='LightBoxHeadingCell' style='display:none;'> Event ID : </td> <td class='LightBoxNormalCell'> <input type='text' id='AssessorEventID' disabled style='display:none;width:150px; background-color: #E2EFFF;'> </td> </tr> <tr id='ReserveRow'> <td class='LightBoxHeadingCell'> <span title='Required' class='Required'>* </span>Reserve Type : </td> <td class='LightBoxNormalCell'> <select id='ReserveTypeDropDown' name='ReserveTypeDropDown'> <option value=''></option> <option selected = '' value='Regular'>Regular</option> <option value='All Call'>All Call</option> </select> </td> <td class='LightBoxHeadingCell'> <span title='Required' class='Required'>* </span>Reserved For : </td> <td class='LightBoxNormalCell'> <select id='ReservedForDropDown' name='ReservedForDropDown'> <option value=''></option> <option selected = '' value='Any'>Any</option> <option value='CAT Only'>CAT Only</option> <option value='In-Person Only'>In-Person Only</option> </select> </td> </tr> <tr id='DatesRow'> <td class='LightBoxHeadingCell' id='StartDateHeadingTD'> <span title='Required' class='Required'>* </span>Start Date : </td> <td id='AssessorsStartDateCalendarTD'> <input type='text' id='AssessorsStartDateCalendar' disabled style='width:150px; background-color: #E2EFFF;'> </td> <td class='LightBoxHeadingCell' id='EndDateHeadingTD'> <span title='Required' class='Required'>* </span>End Date : </td> <td class='LightBoxNormalCell' id='AssessorsEndDateCalendarTD'> <input type='text' id='AssessorsEndDateCalendar' style='width:150px; background-color: #E2EFFF;'> </td> </tr> <tr id='AvailableTimesRow'> <td colspan='4'> <table width='620px' cellspacing='5' style='height: 150px;margin-top: 1px;border: 1px solid black; background-color: #E2EFFF;' id='AvailableTimesTable'> <tbody> <tr> <td colspan='4'>  <table width='100%' border='0'> <tr> <td class='LightBoxHeadingCell'>Available Times : </td> <td class='LightBoxHeadingCell'>&nbsp;</td> <td class='LightBoxHeadingCell'><a class='LightBoxHeadingCell' href='javascript:CheckAllCheckBoxes()'><span class='LightBoxHeadingCell'>Check All</span></a></td> <td class='LightBoxHeadingCell'><a class='LightBoxHeadingCell' href='javascript:UncheckAllCheckBoxes()'><span class='LightBoxHeadingCell'>Uncheck All</span></a></td> </tr> </table>     </td> </tr> <tr> <td class='AvailableTimes' style='color:green;'> <input type='checkbox' name='AvailableTimesCheckboxes' value='08:00 AM - 08:30 AM;'>08:00 AM - 08:30 AM </td> <td class='AvailableTimes' style='color:green;'> <input type='checkbox' name='AvailableTimesCheckboxes' value='08:30 AM - 09:00 AM;'>08:30 AM - 09:00 AM </td> <td class='AvailableTimes' style='color:green;'> <input type='checkbox' name='AvailableTimesCheckboxes' value='09:00 AM - 09:30 AM;'>09:00 AM - 09:30 AM </td> <td class='AvailableTimes' style='color:green;'> <input type='checkbox' name='AvailableTimesCheckboxes' value='09:30 AM - 10:00 AM;'>09:30 AM - 10:00 AM </td> </tr> <tr> <td class='AvailableTimes' style='color:green;'> <input type='checkbox' name='AvailableTimesCheckboxes' value='10:00 AM - 10:30 AM;'>10:00 AM - 10:30 AM </td> <td class='AvailableTimes' style='color:green;'> <input type='checkbox' name='AvailableTimesCheckboxes' value='10:30 AM - 11:00 AM;'>10:30 AM - 11:00 AM </td> <td class='AvailableTimes' style='color:green;'> <input type='checkbox' name='AvailableTimesCheckboxes' value='11:00 AM - 11:30 AM;'>11:00 AM - 11:30 AM </td> <td class='AvailableTimes' style='color:green;'> <input type='checkbox' name='AvailableTimesCheckboxes' value='11:30 AM - 12:00 PM;'>11:30 AM - 12:00 PM </td> </tr> <tr> <td class='AvailableTimes' style='color:green;'> <input type='checkbox' name='AvailableTimesCheckboxes' value='12:00 PM - 12:30 PM;'>12:00 PM - 12:30 PM </td> <td class='AvailableTimes' style='color:green;'> <input type='checkbox' name='AvailableTimesCheckboxes' value='12:30 PM - 01:00 PM;'>12:30 PM - 01:00 PM </td> <td class='AvailableTimes' style='color:green;'> <input type='checkbox' name='AvailableTimesCheckboxes' value='01:00 PM - 01:30 PM;'>01:00 PM - 01:30 PM </td> <td class='AvailableTimes' style='color:green;'> <input type='checkbox' name='AvailableTimesCheckboxes' value='01:30 PM - 02:00 PM;'>01:30 PM - 02:00 PM </td> </tr> <tr> <td class='AvailableTimes' style='color:green;'> <input type='checkbox' name='AvailableTimesCheckboxes' value='02:00 PM - 02:30 PM;'>02:00 PM - 02:30 PM </td> <td class='AvailableTimes' style='color:green;'> <input type='checkbox' name='AvailableTimesCheckboxes' value='02:30 PM - 03:00 PM;'>02:30 PM - 03:00 PM </td> <td class='AvailableTimes' style='color:green;'> <input type='checkbox' name='AvailableTimesCheckboxes' value='03:00 PM - 03:30 PM;'>03:00 PM - 03:30 PM </td> <td class='AvailableTimes' style='color:green;'> <input type='checkbox' name='AvailableTimesCheckboxes' value='03:30 PM - 04:00 PM;'>03:30 PM - 04:00 PM </td> </tr> <tr> <td class='AvailableTimes' style='color:green;'> <input type='checkbox' name='AvailableTimesCheckboxes' value='04:00 PM - 04:30 PM;'>04:00 PM - 04:30 PM </td> <td class='AvailableTimes' style='color:green;'> <input type='checkbox' name='AvailableTimesCheckboxes' value='04:30 PM - 05:00 PM;'>04:30 PM - 05:00 PM </td> <td class='AvailableTimes' style='color:green;'> <input type='checkbox' name='AvailableTimesCheckboxes' value='05:00 PM - 05:30 PM;'>05:00 PM - 05:30 PM </td> <td class='AvailableTimes' style='color:green;'> <input type='checkbox' name='AvailableTimesCheckboxes' value='05:30 PM - 06:00 PM;'>05:30 PM - 06:00 PM </td> </tr> <tr> <td class='AvailableTimes' style='color:green;'> <input type='checkbox' name='AvailableTimesCheckboxes' value='06:00 PM - 06:30 PM;'>06:00 PM - 06:30 PM </td> <td class='AvailableTimes' style='color:green;'> <input type='checkbox' name='AvailableTimesCheckboxes' value='06:30 PM - 07:00 PM;'>06:30 PM - 07:00 PM </td> <td class='AvailableTimes' style='color:green;'> <input type='checkbox' name='AvailableTimesCheckboxes' value='07:00 PM - 07:30 PM;'>07:00 PM - 07:30 PM </td> <td class='AvailableTimes' style='color:green;'> <input type='checkbox' name='AvailableTimesCheckboxes' value='07:30 PM - 08:00 PM;'>07:30 PM - 08:00 PM </td> </tr> <tr> <td class='AvailableTimes' style='color:green;'> <input type='checkbox' name='AvailableTimesCheckboxes' value='08:00 PM - 08:30 PM;'>08:00 PM - 08:30 PM </td> <td class='AvailableTimes' style='color:green;'> <input type='checkbox' name='AvailableTimesCheckboxes' value='08:30 PM - 09:00 PM;'>08:30 PM - 09:00 PM </td> <td class='AvailableTimes' style='color:green;'> <input type='checkbox' name='AvailableTimesCheckboxes' value='09:00 PM - 09:30 PM;'>09:00 PM - 09:30 PM </td> <td class='AvailableTimes' style='color:green;'> <input type='checkbox' name='AvailableTimesCheckboxes' value='09:30 PM - 10:00 PM;'>09:30 PM - 10:00 PM </td> </tr> </tbody> </table> </td> </tr> <tr id='AssessorNotesRow'> <td valign='top' class='LightBoxHeadingCell'> Assessor Notes : </td> <td colspan='3'> <textarea name='AssessorNotes' style='font-size: 11px;border: solid 1px #CCC; width:465px; height:50px; background-color: #E2EFFF;' id='AssessorNotes'> </textarea> </td> </tr> <tr id='BookingNotesRow'> <td valign='top' class='LightBoxHeadingCell'> Booking Notes : </td> <td colspan='3'> <textarea name='BookingNotes' style='font-size: 11px;border: solid 1px #CCC; width:465px; height:50px; background-color: #E2EFFF;' id='BookingNotes'> </textarea> </td> </tr> <tr id='AssessmentsImageRow' style='display:none;'> <td valign='top' class='LightBoxHeadingCell'> Assessments : </td> <td colspan='3'> <img id='ToolTipImage' class='tooltip' src='/files/404048/93171/Info-32.png' height='15' width='15' title='' /> <div id='AssessmentsGrid' style='width:10px;display:none;'> </div> </td> </tr> </tbody> </table> </div>";
     },
     set_value:function(node,value,ev){       
      $('#AssessorEventID').val(ev.EventID || '');  
      $('#ReasonDropDown').val(ev.Reason || ''); 
      $('#ReserveTypeDropDown').val(ev.ReserveType || 'Regular');        
      $('#ReservedForDropDown').val(ev.ReservedFor || 'Any');                          
      $('#AssessorsStartDateCalendar').val(ev.StartDate || ''); 
      $('#AssessorsEndDateCalendar').val(ev.EndDate || '');             
      $('#AssessorNotes').val(ev.AssessorNotes || ''); 
      $('#BookingNotes').val(ev.BookingNotes || '');                                         
     },
     get_value:function(node,ev){ 
      ev.EventID = $('#AssessorEventID').val();              
      ev.LocationType = $('#AssessorsLocationDropDown option:selected').text();
        
      if($('#AssessorsLocationDropDown option:selected').text() != 'Clinic' && $('#AssessorsLocationDropDown option:selected').text() != 'N/A') 
      {       
       if($('#AvailableTimesTable input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 0)
       {
        var GetCurrentAvailableTimes = '';       
         $('#AvailableTimesTable input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function (){
         GetCurrentAvailableTimes += $(this).val();    
        });              
        ev.AvailableTimes = GetCurrentAvailableTimes.substring(0,GetCurrentAvailableTimes.length-1);          
       }
       else
        ev.AvailableTimes = '';                      
       
       if($('#AssessorsLocationDropDown option:selected').text() == 'Evaluators Office') 
       {   
        ev.AssociationCompanyID = ''; 
        ev.AssociationCompanyName = '';  
       }        
       else   
       { 
        ev.AssociationCompanyID = $('#AssessorsLocationDropDown').val();  
        ev.AssociationCompanyName = $('#AssessorsLocationDropDown option:selected').text(); 
       } 
       
       ev.Reason = '';     
       ev.ReserveType =  $('#ReserveTypeDropDown').val();   
       ev.ReservedFor = $('#ReservedForDropDown').val();  
      }
        else if($('#AssessorsLocationDropDown option:selected').text() == 'Clinic') 
        {
       ev.Reason = ''; 
       ev.ReserveType = '';   
       ev.ReservedFor = ''; 
       ev.AssociationCompanyID = $('#ClinicAssociationDropDown').val();   
       ev.AssociationCompanyName = $('#ClinicAssociationDropDown option:selected').text();  
       ev.AvailableTimes = 'N/A';
        }     
        else
        {
         ev.Reason = $('#ReasonDropDown').val();  
         ev.ReserveType = '';   
       ev.ReservedFor = '';          
         ev.AssociationCompanyID = ''; 
         ev.AssociationCompanyName = ''; 
         ev.AvailableTimes = 'N/A';          
        }     
            
      ev.StartDate = $('#AssessorsStartDateCalendar').val(); 
      ev.EndDate = $('#AssessorsEndDateCalendar').val(); 
      ev.AssessorNotes = $('#AssessorNotes').val(); 
      ev.BookingNotes = $('#BookingNotes').val();                              
     },
     focus:function(node){     
      node.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].focus();       
     }
    }     
    
    //===============
    //Data loading
    //===============
    scheduler.config.lightbox.sections  = [{name:'Assessor', height:130, map_to:'text', type:'my_editor'}]      
    
    scheduler.templates.tooltip_text = function(start, end, event){ 
     if(event.LocationType == 'Clinic') 
      return "<b>Date:</b> <span style='font-weight:bold;color:black;'>" + event.StartDate + "</span><br/><b>Explanations:</b> <span style='font-weight:bold;color:black;'>" + event.Status + "</span><br/><b>Location:</b> <span style='font-weight:bold;color:black;'>" + event.LocationType +  "</span><br/><b>Available Times:</b> <span style='font-weight:bold;color:black;'>N/A" + "</span><br/><b>Assessor Notes:</b> <span style='font-weight:bold;color:black;'>" + event.AssessorNotes + "</span> <br/>";     
     else if(event.LocationType == 'N/A') 
      return "<b>Date:</b> <span style='font-weight:bold;color:black;'>" + event.StartDate + "</span><br/><b>Explanations:</b> <span style='font-weight:bold;color:black;'>" + event.Status +  "</span><br/><b>Location:</b> <span style='font-weight:bold;color:black;'>N/A" +  "</span><br/><b>Reason:</b> <span style='font-weight:bold;color:black;'>" + event.Reason + "</span><br/><b>Available Times:</b> <span style='font-weight:bold;color:black;'>N/A" + "</span><br/><b>Assessor Notes:</b> <span style='font-weight:bold;color:black;'>" + event.AssessorNotes + "</span> <br/>";     
     else 
     {   
      if(event.LocationType == 'Evaluators Office')      
       return "<b>Date:</b> <span style='font-weight:bold;color:black;'>" + event.StartDate + "</span><br/><b>Explanations:</b> <span style='font-weight:bold;color:black;'>" + event.Status + "</span><br/><b>Location:</b> <span style='font-weight:bold;color:black;'>" + event.LocationType +  "</span><br/><b>Available Times:</b> <br/><span style='font-weight:bold;color:black;'>" + event.AvailableTimes.replace(/;/g, '<br/>') + "</span><br/><b>Assessor Notes:</b> <span style='font-weight:bold;color:black;'>" + event.AssessorNotes + "</span> <br/>";
      else             
       return "<b>Date:</b> <span style='font-weight:bold;color:black;'>" + event.StartDate + "</span><br/><b>Explanations:</b> <span style='font-weight:bold;color:black;'>" + event.Status + "</span><br/><b>Location:</b> <span style='font-weight:bold;color:black;'>" + event.AssociationCompanyName +  "</span><br/><b>Available Times:</b> <br/><span style='font-weight:bold;color:black;'>" + event.AvailableTimes.replace(/;/g, '<br/>') + "</span><br/><b>Assessor Notes:</b> <span style='font-weight:bold;color:black;'>" + event.AssessorNotes + "</span> <br/>";      
     }
    };
```

```html
<div id="tiptip_content">
  <div style="width: 100%; height: 25px; overflow: hidden; position: relative;" class="xhdr">
    <img style="display: none; position: absolute;" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/media.centrichealth.ca/jsfiles/dhtmlx/dhtmlxGrid/codebase/imgs/sort_desc.gif">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed; margin-right: 20px; padding-right: 20px;" class="hdr">
      <tbody>
        <tr style="height: auto;">
          <th style="height: 0px;"></th>
          <th style="height: 0px;"></th>
          <th style="height: 0px;"></th>
          <th style="height: 0px;"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="color: black; font-size: 9px; vertical-align: top; font-weight: bold;">
            <div class="hdrcell">Ax Name</div>
          </td>
          <td style="color: black; font-size: 9px; vertical-align: top; font-weight: bold;">
            <div class="hdrcell">Claimant</div>
          </td>
          <td style="color: black; font-size: 9px; vertical-align: top; font-weight: bold;">
            <div class="hdrcell">Ax Times</div>
          </td>
          <td style="color: black; font-size: 9px; vertical-align: top; font-weight: bold;">
            <div class="hdrcell">Ax Address</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div style="width: 100%; overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: hidden;" class="objbox">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed;" class="obj">
      <tbody>
        <tr style="height: auto;">
          <th style="height: 0px;"></th>
          <th style="height: 0px;"></th>
          <th style="height: 0px;"></th>
          <th style="height: 0px;"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr class=" ev_dhx_skyblue">
          <td valign="middle" align="left">Functional Abilities Evaluation</td>
          <td valign="middle" align="left">Peter Palancai</td>
          <td valign="middle" align="left">01:00 PM - 04:30 PM</td>
          <td valign="middle" align="left">LifeMark Health (Sunnyside) - Tecumseh - 13311 Tecumseh Rd. E -, Tecumseh, Ontario, N8N 3T4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class=" odd_dhx_skyblue">
          <td valign="middle" align="left">Functional Abilities Evaluation</td>
          <td valign="middle" align="left">Danuta Roznawski</td>
          <td valign="middle" align="left">09:00 AM - 01:00 PM</td>
          <td valign="middle" align="left">LifeMark Health (Sunnyside) - Tecumseh - 13311 Tecumseh Rd. E -, Tecumseh, Ontario, N8N 3T4</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you reproduce the behavior in a JsFiddle?

Comment: I am using jquery.tipTip with DHTMLX Scheduler. It is a lot of DHTMLX Scheduler code. I can't reproduce the behavior in a JsFiddle.

Comment: Any sample of the html where the tooltip randomly activates?

Comment: I have just added the HTML source.

Comment: I was referring to the scheduler's html

Comment: I have just added the scheduler's Code.

Comment: so you use the scheduler's tooltip as well as a tooltip plugin?

Comment: Yes I am using both.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85228/discussion-between-karim-ali-and-loli).

Comment: Am I blind or there is no question or typed scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Are you including the css file in your html?  Have you tried wrapping in in a function like this:

```
$(function(){

    $('.tooltip').tipTip({maxWidth: 'auto', edgeOffset: 5, defaultPosition: 'top', keepAlive: false, activation: "hover"});

});
```

Comment: CSS is included in the page and wrapping didn't work too.

Comment: Do you have other elements on your form with tooltip as a class?  that would make mousing over any of those other elements fire the tooltip.

Comment: There is tooltip attached to each event on the scheduler for a specific person on a specific date.